# primefaces tags not recognized by myEclipse java enterprise

Tags: jsf, primefaces, myeclipse

i have added the `primefaces6.0.jar` to my project `build path`. and i have also used `taglib` like

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xml:lang="en" lang="en"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
```

and in my xhtml code when i wrote `<p:spinner />` than it was'nt recognized by myEclipse

Comment: Have you added priimefaces jar ? if so try removing that xml:lang="en" lang="en" from your code also change the html to xhtml.

Comment: yes i have added and i have also removed xml:lang="en" lang="en", but didnt worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have enabled the JSF facet (right-click the project in the MyEclipse Explorer, select MyEclipse->Project Facets->Install Java Server Faces Facet). Also ensure the jar is also added to the Deployment Assembly (normally, adding to the deployment assembly instead of the classpath is recommended - it gets added to the classpath automatically), if you want to deploy the application from MyEclipse.

Comment: it worked, by installing Java Server Facet. you saved my day, thumbs up!!